Linear Analysis Chapter 2 Exercise 16

I've been able to show pretty easily that $\|x\|'$ is a norm, but I'm running into difficulty showing that $d_0$ is complete (I'm not sure if it even is). I've approached this by just showing cauchy sequences converge. I think I've shown that they converge pointwise, but I'm having difficulty showing that the candidate is in fact in $d_0$ or that it converges under the norm. My work is as follows:
Let $(x^{(n)}) \subset d_0$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then, $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n_\varepsilon$ s.t. $\forall n>m>n_0$ we have:
$$
\|x^{(n)}-x^{(m)}\| = \sup_l \left\{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^l (x^{(n)}-x^{(m)})_{k}^{\ast}}{\sum_{k=1}^l b_k}\right\} < \varepsilon
$$
And thus, for every $l$ we have that
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^l (x^{(n)}-x^{(m)})_{k}^{\ast}}{\sum_{k=1}^l b_k} < \varepsilon
$$
For $l = 1$, we have:
$$\frac{|x_1^{(n)\ast} - x^{(m)\ast}_1|}{b_1}\le \frac{(x^{(n)}-x^{(m)})_{1}^{\ast}}{b_1} < \varepsilon$$
Thus, we have $x^{(n)\ast}_1\to x_1^{\ast}$
For $l = 2$, we have
$$\frac{(x^{(n)}-x^{(m)})_{1}^{\ast} + (x^{(n)}-x^{(m)})_{2}^{\ast}}{b_1 + b_2} < \varepsilon$$ And after some algebraic manipulation, we get:
$$
\frac{(x^{(n)}-x^{(m)})_{2}^{\ast}}{b_2} < \varepsilon
$$
Inductively we can show this convergence pointwise to $x_n^\ast$. But after this I'm stuck.
I have a feeling I have to employ the Stolz Cesaro theorem to prove that $x_n^\ast$ is indeed in $d_0$, but I am having difficulty proving the following:
$$
\frac{x_n^\ast}{b_n}\to l \in \mathbb R
$$
Any help would be appreciated.

This might be a bit of cheating, but we can rewrite $\|\cdot\|’$ in a way to make this far simpler. Let $\Sigma_\infty$ be the group of permutations of $\mathbb{N}$; $\mathbb{T}$ be the unit circle, regarded as a subset of the complex plane. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $u_1, \cdots, u_n \in \mathbb{T}$, and $s \in \Sigma_\infty$, we define the bounded linear functional $\varphi_{n, u_1, \cdots, u_n, s} \in (c_0)^\ast$ by,
$$\varphi_{n, u_1, \cdots, u_n, s}((x_n)) = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n u_ix_{s(i)}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n b_i}$$
Then one may verify that $\|(x_n)\|’ = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}, u_1, \cdots, u_n \in \mathbb{T}, s \in \Sigma_\infty} |\varphi_ {n, u_1, \cdots, u_n, s}((x_n))|$. We also observe that $\|(x_n)\|_\infty \leq b_1\|(x_n)\|’$. From these, it is not hard to conclude the proof that $d_0$ is complete, so I’ll leave the details to OP.

Why do we need the $u_i$s? I don't get the motivation. Shouldn't $|(x_n)|'$ just be $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N, s \in \Sigma_\infty} |\varphi((x_n))|$?, where there is no $u_i$ in the definition of $\varphi$

@AndrewLys Without $u_i$, $x_{s(i)}$ could have different phases that cancel each other out (if it makes it clearer, think of different signs in the real case). As a concrete example, if $x_1=1$, $x_2=-1$, and $x_n=0$ for $n>2$, then $x_1^\ast=x_2^\ast=1$, so $x_1^\ast+x_2^\ast=2$, but without $u_i$, the sum of two $x_i$ can only be $1$, $-1$, or $0$, but never something of absolute value $2$, as is needed.

(A slight correction: $\varphi$ is just a number, so I shouldn’t have used the norm sign in the supremum. Instead, I should have just used absolute value. I just fixed that in an edit to the answer.)

@AndrewLys If you find the answer satisfactory, there's a checkmark on the left to accept the answer. You don't actually have to do a bounty for this.

Heh I put a bounty on it to see if anyone could come up with a more elegant solution, but after some consideration, I figured this is indeed fairly elegant.
